# Errors in header file with function taking structs

Tags: c

What's wrong with this header? Gcc throws out:

```
 libmmbox.h:7:29: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
 libmmbox.h:8:27: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
```

Here's my code:

```
#ifndef __LIBMMBOX_H__
#define __LIBMMBOX_H__

int mmbox_connect(char *username);
int mmbox_login(int token, char *password);
int mmbox_quit();
int mmbox_stat(mmbox_stat_t *result);
int mmbox_list(mmbox_mail **l, int *num_msg);
int mmbox_send(char *dest, char *obj, void *buf, size_t size);
int mmbox_rcv(int id, void *buf, size_t size);
int mmbox_delete(int id);
int mmbox_resume(int id);

typedef struct
{
    char *user;     
    int used_space; 
    int free_space; 
    int num_msg;    
} mmbox_stat_t;

typedef struct 
{
    char *sender, *recipient; /
    char *obj, *date;         
    char flags;                      
    size_t size;              
} mmbox_mail;

#endif
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mmbox_stat_t struct is declared after it is used into a function signature. So the compiler doesn't still know this type when you declare:

```
int mmbox_stat(mmbox_stat_t *result);
```

Put your function prototypes after data structures definition.